# Работа с ресурсами. Какая проблема есть в следующем коде?

Tags: java, resources

Если есть проблема то как можно исправить?
Классы SomeResource и ResourceManager даны по условию, протестированы и принято что работают правильно. Требуется их только использовать правильно...

```
// resourceManager is created and initialized correctly
...
//Acquire a limited resource
SomeResource r = resourceManager.acquire();
r.use();
//Now release the resource to be available for other users
resourceManager.release(r);
```

Comment: может быть проблема высвобождения ресурсов при возникновении исключения...тогда лучше все обернуть в try catch finally

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ

Answer (score 3):

Если метод `use()` небезопасен относительно исключений, то этот код может привести к тому, что ресурс не будет освобожден.

```
SomeResource r = resourceManager.acquire();
try {
  r.use();
} catch (Exception e) {
  ...
} finally {
  //Now release the resource to be available for other users
  resourceManager.release(r);
}
```

Comment: Можно использовать конструкцию "try-catch с ресурсами": `try(FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("file.txt")) {

        int data = input.read();
        while(data != -1){
            System.out.print((char) data);
            data = input.read();
        }
    }`
http://hasysdev.blogspot.ru/2012/06/try-java-7.html

Comment: Для этого класс должен реализовывать интерфейс `AutoClosable`, поскольку о `SomeResource` ничего не известно, то данный подход некорректен.